Match records where array field of objects contain matches possibly on different records
Suppose I have an array field that may look like:
{
  "tags": [
    { "type": "A", "name": "something" },
    { "type": "B", "name": "whatever" }
  ]
}

Is there a way to query for records with some tag

type: B
and name: something

Such that we match whether or not it match 1 tag record or 2

Tldr;
I believe with a default mapping this is the behaviour of elasticsearch.
If this is not working could you please share the mapping of the index ? You re most likely using nested
Demo
The following request allowed me to search and get document 1
PUT /79250167/_doc/1
{
  "tags": [
    { "type": "A", "name": "something" },
    { "type": "B", "name": "whatever" }
  ]
}


GET 79250167/_search
{
  "query":{
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "tags.type.keyword":{
              "query": "B",
              "_name": "type matching"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match":{
            "tags.name.keyword": {
              "query": "something",
              "_name": "name matching"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Should give you the document. As well as witch clause has been matching.
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 0.723315,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "79250167",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.723315,
        "_source": {
          "tags": [
            {
              "type": "A",
              "name": "something"
            },
            {
              "type": "B",
              "name": "whatever"
            }
          ]
        },
        "matched_queries": [
          "name matching",
          "type matching"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

